# Select value from a (SET) list

Tags: mysql

I am building a blog website with php.

I have a table with a column SET(Y,N,X,A).

And I want to categorize each value.

for example:
A post has labels: News, World, Tropical... selected from the SET of values in the database.

And now I want to get every post from the database that has "News" as label.
I've been really struggling 2 days to find an answer!!!

Comment: Post at least what you have tried, some code, 2 days is enough to have some working (even with errors) code to start with. A better description of tables structure is also helpful.

Comment: My example is more obvious than the reality itself! I have a column SET('Y','N') and I want to check. If row has 'N', then reveal!!

Comment: `WHERE label = 'N'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution by myself, thanks to Rick James for giving me an enlightenment.

The Right MySql call for this, is

```
SELECT * WHERE labels LIKE 'N'
```

Just to mention:
labels is a SET('Y','N') column and I want to check, if a row has value 'Y' or 'N'
then get the row.

The SET column doesn't work with `labels='N'` because by default is `labels='Y','N'`